# The Interpreter and Reverse Polish Notation

Tags: computer-science, postfix-notation

Using a high level language, is it the job of the interpreter/compiler to convert mathematical expressions from infix notation into postfix or prefix before execution. In fact, do infix expressions need to be converted at all for them to be "processed"? I'm trying to understand what is going on "behind the scences" a little. I'm fine however with the concept of the stack and its use with RPN.

Comment: Are you asking about a specific language or hardware architecture? Usually the program stack is not at all related to the operand stack you get in RPN.

Comment: I'm trying to get an understanding of the point of PN. While it's another way to represent an expression why does it exist - do computers require expressions to be in PN format? Sorry if the question is slightly ambiguous.

Comment: They do not require it as such, no, but an expression in RPN form is quite easy to evaluate using just a value stack, and also simpler than a traditional expression to convert into native code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Reverse or not) Polish Notation is not used internally by computers: it's entirely for humans. It gained popularity as it was a way to represent quite complex arithmetic expressions for electronic calculators, back when they weren't sophisticated enough to understand operator precedence and brackets, like today's calculators. The engineers who "grew up" with those calculators got used to thinking in that way, so naturally the first calculator programs on general-purpose computers worked in the same way.

When you write an expression in a programming language, the parser (the part of the interpreter or compiler that understands the language) turns that expression into a tree, where each node of the tree is an operation, and each child of that node is an operand of the expression. For example,

```
f(3 + 4)
```

might be a "function call" node, whose first child is the name `f`, and whose second child is an "add" node. The children of the "add" node are "literal" nodes (i.e. values) whose values are 3 and 4.

This tree is called an *abstract syntax tree* (AST) because it's a tree whose structure is separate from the syntax of the language (i.e. the syntax is abstracted away). In a compiler like gcc which understands several different languages, the parser for each language produces the same kind of AST, and it doesn't matter whether the original language used RPN, or maths-style infix notation, or only function calls.

The parser then gives this to the backend. In an interpreter, the backend will just evaluate each node one at a time, most likely starting from the bottom. That is, first it replaces the "add" node and its children with the value 7, then it looks up the function named `f`, then it replaces the "function call node" and its children with the result of the function call.

A compiler instead translates the tree into a sequence of instructions. In this example, they might be something like:

> load 3 into register 0
>   load 4 into register 1
>   add registers 0 and 1, and put the answer in register 0
>   jump to the code for `f`, which expects its argument in register 0
>   use the result in register 0

Obviously the instructions aren't quite so wordy as that: they're written in *assembly language*, which is usually specific to the target architecture (the type of computer you're compiling for). I won't show a whole assembly program, but the add instruction might look like:

```
add r0, r0, r1
```

The last step of a compiler is the *assembler*, which then translates each instruction of the assembly program into a number, which the actual CPU understands.

There's no RPN or stack of operands in any of this. The "stack" you hear about programs using (such as the one in the name of this website) is a region of memory which (kind of) grows automatically. The program can use this to store things which are too big to fit in registers, or which would be wiped out by function calls (because the called function wants to use the register you were using).

There have been [CPU architectures that actually did use a stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based), and the assembly language for the CPU looked a bit like RPN. The "virtual machine" used by [PostScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript) is an example, and [Lisp Machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_machine) are/were a genuine hardware example. No CPU architectures that are popular today work this way, though.

Comment: Your instruction example as a whole is in fact following Reverse Polish Notation. As you point out, each instruction itself is in Prefix Polish Notation (not Infix Notation).

Comment: @hylitiz It is kind-of similar, but the key difference is that in Polish or Reverse Polish, you can chain operations together directly e.g. `1 2 + 4 *` adds one and two, and then multiplies the result of that by four. In my assembly language example, each line is a single operation which writes to a particular register. The assignment of results to registers is explicit in the assembly language form, and this is the only way that operations are combined.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it is quite similar. In that assembly language form, can we define juxtaposition (one line after another) as chain operation for expressions? In that case, doesn't it become Polish again?

Comment: @hyiltiz Not really, because in a register-based architecture, it's the registers named by each operation that determine how they connect. e.g. `add r0 1 2; add r1 3 4; sub r0 r0 r1` does (1+2) - (3+4), and it does the same if you swap the first two instructions. The RPN equivalent is `1 2 + 3 4 + -`, but `3 4 + 1 2 + -` does (3+4) - (1+2) instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely up to the design of a specific language - as long as the correctness of computations is assured, whether they're done infix, postfix or any other way.

Comment: Thanks, so I guess I'm trying to understand the need for Polish Notation

Comment: @tommyd456 Well, wiki has some nice explanations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation#Practical_implications